Jmeter html report giving bad request even if the jmeter view result tree is not any showing error
Jmeter hmlr report showing 400 error


View Results Tree listener won't give you request and response details if you use CSV mode for .jtl results file.
If you want to see request and response details you need to add another listener like Simple Data Writer and configure it to save request and response headers and data for failed requests:

Then once your test is completed you can open errors.jtl file with View Results Tree listener and see what request did you send and what went wrong, maybe the system under test will tell you what is the error in your request
More information: How to Save Response Data in JMeter
